# How to read meta properties from RowInstance in Orange?

Tags: python, widget, orange

I want to display information from `RowInstance`. The following code snippets display most attributes.

```
# type(line) is Orange.data.table.RowInstance
for i, cell in enumerate(line.values()):
    print(cell.value)
```

However, "metadata values" are not accessible from the method `values()`. Only the feature values are returned.

How can I access metadata from `RowInstance`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found one way to read the metadata attributes

The [Domain](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.domain.html) property contains the [attributes](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.domain.html#Orange.data.Domain.attributes) list and the [metadata](https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.domain.html#Orange.data.Domain.metas) list.

```
>>> line.domain.attributes[0].name
"Feature1"
>>> line.domain.metas[0].name
"Metadata1"
```

The domain also has an utility function that get the attributes/meta index from its name. This lead to the discovery that metadata values are located in the negative indexes (-1,-2,-3,...).

```
>>> line.domain.index("Feature1")
0
>>> line.domain.index("Metadata1")
-1
```

With the index, it is then possible to get the value for the `RowInstance` (line variable).

```
>>> line[0]
Value('Feature1', Hello)
>>> line[0].value
"Hello"
>>> line[-2].value
4.0
```

Ref : https://docs.orange.biolab.si/3/data-mining-library/reference/data.domain.html